# Add an outlet to a porch light?

Tags: receptacle

I replaced a porch wall light fixture for a motion sensing one, but the old fixture had an interesting feature: the mounting box was extended so it had an electrical outlet mounted in the side of it.

Is there an extension box that has a mounting for an outlet on it, so that I can add back an outdoor outlet?  If so, what is such a device called?

**update**: I don’t have a picture of the fixture (it was done for a friend), but here’s one on Amazon with a similar box: https://smile.amazon.com/Outdoor-Industrial-Exterior-Waterproof-Farmhouse/dp/B09BD36C7G/

Comment: Please post a pic. It will help get you the best answer.

Comment: It seems to be manufacturer specific so you just need to find a motion-sensing fixture with an outlet. You could always choose to build and waterproof your own outlet enclosure and attach the motion sensing fixture to it.

Comment: @HoneyDo: I linked to a similar product, which has pictures

Comment: I was under the impression for years that light-fixture-mounted outlets are no longer allowed under electrical code.

Comment: @KyleB : well, that would explain why I can’t find anything.  (And it makes sense, as you need a box that can support the moment & weight of the fixture, so it would be easy to screw up)

Comment: Right - And note the fixture you linked doesn't say "UL approved"...  Even if it said it was, I wouldn't believe it!!!   Buyer beware on Amazon!!!!

Comment: Google also shows it(or similar unit) being sold at Home Depot, which should care about UL units.  Do think it is a handy feature if safe, probably better than those screw in outlets.

Comment: @KyleB I would consider NEC 210.52 Where it says "This section provides requirements for 125-volt, 15- and 20-ampere receptacle outlets. The receptacles required by this section shall be in addition to any receptacle that is as follows:
*(1) Part of a luminaire* or appliance*, so it seems they aren't prohibited, but they don't satisfy required locations

Comment: I'm curious why it's useful to have an outlet in the middle of a porch ceiling?   Is it for permanent string lights or some other permanent, plugged-in ceiling fixture?   If so it might be more practical and useful to install a standard outdoor outlet somewhere else on the ceiling, with power originating from the existing ceiling box or from the switch box controlling it.  As long as you're already up on a ladder installing stuff in the ceiling!

Comment: @jay613 : not a ceiling, it’s wall mounted. (see the link). And you’re now required to have an outlet on the front and back of residences, so I suspect that this would be a way for people rehabbing old houses to do it without needing to pull a new circuit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no prohibition on receptacles in light fixtures in a bathroom or outside.

there is a requirement for both to have GFCI protection and this is why they have largely disappeared.

the Amazon fixture in the above question appears to have GFCI , and if you scroll down it looks like it is ETL listed (ETL is equivalent to UL)

As far as a light fixture box that has a receptacle I have never used one or seen one.

we would normally put a single gang box and outlet in or purchase that expensive fixture.

specialty parts become very expensive so installing a light box and single gang will end up being standard parts less expensive in the long run.

Could there be a listed box made for a WR-GFCI that you mount a lamp on sure but as I said I haven’t seen one and the use would be limited to a damp location unless a extra duty cover was added for wet locations making the box uglier (I don’t think that combo exists for just a box,

Comment: I’ve been thinking about it, and I suspect that the issue isn’t simply if it can deal with the extra forces, but you would add an opening further from the wall and less protected by the roof overhang if it’s not an covered porch.  The all-in-one units are probably much safer from an electrical fire risk standpoint

Comment: Joe I would agree that part of the problem is the distance away from the vertical surface. But it’s not a fire issue at all more that the fixture would not look as nice.